# Magento only one product showing on category page

Tags: php, magento, categories

[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRN4f.jpg)
   As you can see in the SS above, only one of the products in my category is being shown on the view. BUT notice that it says there are 3 items in the category. Any thoughts on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. And before you say it, I have already tried all the following standard fixes that can be found on google such as:

- The products must be Visible in Catalog.
- The products must be Enabled.
- Product must have a stock Quantity.
- The product must be set to In Stock. If the product is set not to
  track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In
  Stock.
- The product must be assigned to the target Category.
- If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through
  Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
- You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Make `all category anchor(is_anchor=1) is yes ,from design of tab category`

and set `store id to all Products`

And `Re indexing all index from Admin>system>Index management`

Comment: found it but this still did not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Products will also not show up if you upload new products and missed the 'URL Key' field. Filling in this field will add the product to the category page.